# Find the limit of the following convergent sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I find the limits of
$$a_n=\ln(3n^2+1)−\ln(n^2+4)$$
Don't even know how to start. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: $$\log\dfrac ab=\log a-\log b$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: $$\ln(a)-\ln(b) = \ln \frac{a}{b}.$$

> $$a_n = \ln \frac{3n^2+1}{n^2+4}.$$

Hint 2: If you can compute $\lim_n c_n$, then $$\lim_n \ln(c_n) = \ln (\lim_n c_n)$$ because the logarithm is continuous.

> Compute $\lim_n \frac{3n^2+1}{n^2+4}$, then take the logarithm to get your final answer.

Answer (score 0):

As n grows very large and aproaches infinity, a_n approaches ln(3n^2)-ln(n^2). This is ln(3).

Answer (score 0):

For a convergent sequence

$\lim\limits_{x \to\infty}a_n=L$

In this case

$$a_n=\ln(3n^2+1)-\ln(n^2+4)\\=\ln\bigg(\dfrac{3n^2+1}{n^2+4}\bigg)\\\therefore L=\lim\limits_{x \to\infty}\ln\bigg(\dfrac{3n^2+1}{n^2+4}\bigg)\\=\lim\limits_{x \to\infty}\ln\left(\dfrac{3+\dfrac{1}{n^2}}{1+\dfrac{4}{n^2}}\right)\\=\ln\left(\dfrac{3+0}{1+0}\right)\\=\ln3$$

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the log as one term, so you end up having $\ln[(3n^2+1)/(n^2+4)]$. Taking the limit of this as $x\to\infty$ yields a final limit of $\ln(3)$.